# Why JAWS does not read label before value?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

Hi I'm adding ARIA support to my HTML page and test it with JAWS.
I have a problem with implementing pairs of label and value elements.
It is not a form, it's text.

**Description of problem:**

What I had before:

```
<span class="label"> 
  Home location 
</span>
<span class="value"> 
  Lviv
</span>
```

After adding ARIA:

```
<span class="label" aria-label="home location" id="home_location">
  Home location
</span>
<span class="value" aria-labelledby="home_location" role="definition">
  Lviv
</span>
```

So, now screen reader should read something like:

`Label "Home location", Value "Lviv"`

But, unfortunately, JAWS read it in reverse order:

`Value "Lviv", Label "Home location"`

P.S. I know that use `<span>` elements for label-value pair is not good, I don't want to change it, cause I can broke existing css-html rules and page structure..

**Question:**

How can I change my HTML code or ARIA attributes to read it in correct order - label information prior value?

Environment - Windows7, JAWS 16

Thanks.

Comment: I've made a test page. Here JAWS 16.0.4350 says "Home location Lviv". I'm using IE 11 under Windows 7. What setup do you have: JAWS version, browser, Windows version? Мої вам вітання з Черкас :))

Comment: I am agree with @andre-polykanine. I have check with nvda in chrome, result is same as andre-polykanine. might be JAWS configuration form field reading option enabled.